# “Too many calls per IP address” always at the same request count, even when using different amounts of proxies/accounts

Tags: python, proxy, python-requests

I created a program that claims usernames upon availability. It works fine, however after 3500 requests I get an error code from the api that there are `too many calls per IP address.` However I use rotating proxies and accounts, and even if I have 1000 proxies and accounts loaded it still happens at 3500 requests. My `proxies` function returns a random proxy from a list, and the same goes for my `accounts` function.

My checking function:

```
    def checker(self):
        while True:
            self.proxy = self.proxies()
            [self.usernames.put(line.strip()) for line in open("external/wordlist.txt")]  
            name = self.usernames.get(); self.usernames.put(name)
            url = f"https://public-ubiservices.ubi.com/v3/profiles?nameOnPlatform={name}&platformType=uplay"   
            try:
                if len(name) > 2:
                    r = requests.get(url, headers=self.headers, proxies=self.proxy)
                    if self.checkedCount % 75 == 0:
                        self.checkedCount += 1
                        self.proxy = self.proxies()
                        self.login()
                    
                    if r.status_code == 200:
                        self.checkedCount += 1
                        if len(r.json()['profiles']) != 0:
                            print(f"{Fore.LIGHTBLACK_EX}[+]{Fore.RESET} Taken:          {name}")          
                        else:  
                            print(f"{Fore.LIGHTBLACK_EX}[+]{Fore.RESET} Available:      {name}") 
                            self.create(name)
                    
                    else:
                        print(f"{Fore.LIGHTBLACK_EX}[+]{Fore.RESET} Error:          /errors.txt")
                        with open('external/errors.txt', "a") as errorFile:
                            errorFile.write(f"{datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M')} | Error message: {r.text}\n")
                        self.errorCount += 1
                        self.proxy = self.proxies()
                        self.login()
                        time.sleep(25)
            except:
                pass
```

Account and proxy function:

```
    with open('external/proxies.txt', 'r') as proxyFile:
        proxyList = [proxyIp.strip() for line in proxyFile.readlines() for proxyIp in line.split(',') if proxyIp]
        
    with open('external/credentials.txt', 'r') as accountFile:
        accountList = [line.strip() for line in accountFile]
...

    def accounts(self):
        try:
            self.randomLogin = random.choice(self.accountList)
            login = base64.b64encode(bytes(self.randomLogin, 'utf-8'))
            self.finalLogin = (login.decode("utf-8"))
            return self.finalLogin
        except:
            self.errorCount += 1
            pass

    def proxies(self):
        try:
            self.proxy = random.choice(self.proxyList)
            againProxy = self.proxy.replace("{'http': 'http://", "")
            self.finalProxy = againProxy.replace("'}", "")
            return {'http': f'http://{self.proxy}',}
        except:
            pass
```

Comment: Are you sure you do you rotate proxies at all? We don't see `self.proxyList` and we cannot tell whether the `proxies()` method works fine all the time or the bare `except` just mask some error. From the error you get I would guess it fails somehow.

Comment: Also the proxy you pass is just for `http`, while the url protocol is `https`